# CORS HTTP headers is added twice

Tags: javascript, http, cors, iis-8

I develop a full javascript website based on Openlayers. In one of the layers added in the map, I want to display png markers. The images are on another domain than my site. The site which hosts these images is on IIS 8.

To get the images, I put the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

But I get the error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,*'
```

If I delete the headers, I have the (normal) error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Origin 'http://gismodule.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The headers are specified only once, so I don't understand why the message said 'multiple values'.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is not that the header itself is added twice but the value contains two asterisks: `*,*`. Could you try and change the value of the header to just `*`?

Comment: Thank you Martin for your answer. I just put one *. the second appears I do not know how.

Comment: @MartinSchneider — I wouldn't be surprised if the server interpreted "Add header foo: *, Add header foo: *" to mean "generate a single header with comma separated values".

Comment: Do you also have Access-Control-Allow-Credentials set to true?  Have you tried your specific domain value instead of `*`?

Comment: @AK3800  - No, I haven't credentials. With a specific domain, I have the same problem with an error like `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*,http://[...].mydomain'.`

Comment: I apologize if this seems like a stupid question, but I'd rather address it specifically than leave it implied... The images you're trying to access on the remote site, do you have access to that site and is that where you are putting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the response? Or are you adding that header to your request (the client) when calling to get the images?

Comment: I get it! @AK3800, your question is not so stupid , it helped me to find the problem. In fact, the website uses `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`, thing it didn't know. So there was a confilct between the CORS defined on server side by the WebAPI and the headers defined in IIS. So we keep the CORS      in the webAPI, and add headers `Access-Control-Allow-Originin` in IIS, **only at the root of the directory which contains images**. And it works!Thank you everybody for your help!

Comment: @Gis Module, great, I'm glad it helped point you in the right direction!